# A program that "press" the x button N times

Tags: windows

I wonder if it is possible to create a program, using notepad and command prompt in windows, that acts like my fingers on the keyboard. I think the best way to explain what I mean is with an example.

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
    "press key x"
    "wait 3 seconds"
}
```

So basically I want a program that acts as if I was hitting the x button every third second, a total of N times. If the answer is yes, it is possible, could you recommend a site, pdf or similar from where I could learn how to write such a program.

I hope that I have made myself clear, if there is anything in my question that should be improved, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) is a nice option.

Here's a sample script:

```
Loop, 3
{
send, xxxxx
Sleep, 3000 
}
```

Comment: Error: parameter #3 invalid. Specifically: 3000 }

Comment: I was thinking that I'd play around with the sample you gave me, and it returned an error.

Comment: try it with the above edited version.  When I posted it the newlines were removed for some reason.

Comment: Cool. Accept as answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can look into `keybd_event` and `SendInput` APIs for keyboard input, and `Sleep` for waiting.

For example, with `keybd_event`

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
    keybd_event((BYTE)VkKeyScan(L'x'), MapVirtualKey(VkKeyScan(L'x'), MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), 0, 0);
    keybd_event((BYTE)VkKeyScan(L'x'), MapVirtualKey(VkKeyScan(L'x'), MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    Sleep(3000);
}
```

With `SendInput`:

```
INPUT inputs[1];

inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputs[0].ki.wVk = VkKeyScan(L'x');
inputs[0].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VkKeyScan(L'x'), MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
inputs[0].ki.time = 0;
inputs[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

for(i = 0; i < N;  i++)
{
    inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    Sleep(3000);
}
```